# React & SASS - Styles won't apply on child components

Tags: reactjs, sass, webpack

I have a problem with styling child components, something like this:

```
/*parent component*/

import './styleguide/main.scss';


export default function AppRoot(props) {
  return (

<BrowserRouter>

    <Provider store={props.store}>

        <Routes/>

    </Provider>

</BrowserRouter>
  );
}


/*somewhere in child component*/

<button className='btn' type="button" onClick={() => fields.push({})}>
 New Active Substance
 </button>
```

Actually, styles will work **only** if I import them directly in child component like this: 
`import styles from '../main.scss'`
and apply them as `classNames={styles.btn}`

So, how can i get it works in parent and apply them in child as `classNames='btn'` ?

Comment: Can you show me your webpack.config.js file?

Comment: You have defined css-modules as a part of your webpack pipeline. Css-modules transform your css names to avoid collisions. It is good to understand your webpack config before start writing an application. It will help you to avoid pitfalls like this one.

Comment: @RafaelBerro 

Here is whole webpack.config.dev.js file --> https://www.dropbox.com/s/wx69ixha2rp4dp2/webpack.config.dev.js?dl=0

Comment: @niba Thank you, actually css-modules was in mern boilerplate by default and I wasn't paying attention

Comment: Your webpack.config.js file are missing the  sass-loader module. Check out this [boilerplate](https://github.com/rhberro/the-react-client) that I am developing, it uses everything that you actually need.

Comment: There is sass-loader

Answer (score 0):

Pass Style object as a props to the child component and access in child components

Comment: Can you show me a simple example how to properly do that? Thank you in advance